# mongodb deleteOne method not deleting data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to delete a mongodb data by specifying an id but the `deleteOne` method is not working. Where did I go wrong. What is the right way to use the `deleteOne` method to delete a data in a collection.

```js
const User = require('../models/user')

User.collection.deleteOne({"_id": `ObjectId(563jjkhskdkjkbxvs)`})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('deleted')
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Comment: @Porok12 the id i mentioned here is random. The id i'm using on my side is correct

Comment: You are using `mongoose` or `mongodb`?

Comment: @Porok12 im using mongoose on a mongoDB database

Comment: I would try `User.collection.deleteOne({"_id": "563jjkhskdkjkbxvs"})`

Comment: @Porok12 I already tried that it doesn't delete the data

Comment: In my project I'm using `db.Project.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id})` and it works fine. Can you provide more context like schema, real db entity, and context how you call this code?

Comment: Why are you doing User.collection, simple User.deleteOne should work

Comment: @CharchitKapoor depends what he exports in `require('../models/user')`

Comment: @Porok12 Thanks for mentioning mongoose. I went to their docs and got a working solution. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

A mongoose specific solution works as expected!

```js
const User = require('../models/user')

User.findOneAndRemove({
    _id: '563jjkhskdkjkbxvs'
  },
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log('deleted')
    }
  });
```

Comment: Here you have `User.findOneAndRemove` in question you have `User.collection.deleteOne`, `deleteOne` should work too, but it seems that you need to remove `.collection` part